# How can I restrict the use of my function by macro, like private in C++?

Tags: c, macros

For example, in a program, I have a function that is used internally by other functions. But I want to restrict the use of this helping function in `main()`. Like `private` in C++.

Comment: Surely you meant class methods, but to clear things up for further readers, worth saying, that you can not make free functions private in C++: to hide them you don't declare it in publicly available headers and either make them static (C way) or put them in anonymous namespace (C++ way).

Comment: Are you interested in C only answers? I'm asking because some user clairvoyantly decided that C++ tag was redundant.

Comment: Some guys just changed title and tags, so it is really unclear now what was asked first. Who the **** approves such edits?

Answer (score 7):

You make the function `static` in your C file (which I assume is *not* the same C file as the one that has `main()`) and omit it in your header. Then it won't be callable from outside its own C file.

Answer (score 0):

Define and use it in a separate compilation unit or `#undef` it at the end of your header if you must use it there. Are you sure you want a macro for what you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use #if and #endif for certain functions and declare them under a specific condition in the header file. The following example might help:

```
#if SPECIFIC_CONDITION
void functionOne();
BOOL functionTwo();
int functionThree();
#endif
void functionFour();
```

Thus all functions except functionFour() will act as private as you can call the top three functions under a specific condition only

Answer (score -3):

Well, you put that function as private member of some struct or class so that you alone may use it and nobody else.

Comment: I am not downvoter but telling you reason of down vote  he is asking specifically for language `c` not c++